# Change the vline thickness and font sizes of sjPlot::plot_model() output

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I am trying to change the aesthetics of my plot_model() graph and am struggling. Specifically, I'd like to:

- Make the 1:1 line (vline?) thicker
- Increase the font size of the labels

Current graph output when using the code below:

[image]

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(sjPlot)

# Run the model
plotModel <- glmer(used ~ BareGround + ConiferTreeCanopy + DeciduousTreeCanopy + 
                          Developed + MesicGrass + MesicShrub + Water + XericGrass + 
                          XericShrub + (1|id) + (1|month), 
                   family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                   data = plotData, na.action="na.fail")

# Plot the results
set_theme(base = theme_light())

state1plot <- plot_model(plotModel, show.values = TRUE, show.p = FALSE, 
                         value.offset = 0.3, title = "", 
                         axis.labels = c("Xeric Shrubs", "Xeric Grasses", "Water", 
                                         "Mesic Shrubs", "Mesic Grasses", "Developed", 
                                         "Deciduous Tree Canopy", "Conifer Tree Canopy", 
                                         "Bare Ground"), 
                          axis.lim = c(0.01, 20), 
                          colors = c("#C43302", "#EDAA25"), 
                          vline.color = "#061423", 
                          dot.size = 8, line.size = 3) + 
               theme(text = element_text(size = 20))

state1plot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found any arguments to achieve that directly via `plot_model`. But one option would be to manipulate the `ggplot` object directly. To this end you first have to figure the index of the `hline` and the `text` layers. Then set the `size` for these directly via the `aes_params` element.

As you provided no example data I use one of the default examples from `?lme4::glmer`:

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(ggplot2)
library(sjPlot)

# Run the model
plotModel <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
  data = cbpp, family = binomial
)

# Plot the results
set_theme(base = theme_light())
state1plot <- plot_model(plotModel,
  show.values = TRUE, show.p = FALSE,
  value.offset = 0.3, title = "",
  axis.labels = c(
    "Xeric Shrubs", "Xeric Grasses", "Water", "Mesic Shrubs",
    "Mesic Grasses", "Developed", "Deciduous Tree Canopy",
    "Conifer Tree Canopy", "Bare Ground"
  ), axis.lim = c(0.01, 20), colors = c("#C43302", "#EDAA25"),
  vline.color = "#061423", dot.size = 8, line.size = 1
)  + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))

# vline
state1plot$layers[[1]]$aes_params$size <- 4
# labels
state1plot$layers[[4]]$aes_params$size <- 8

state1plot
```

[image]